# Show progress of Mercurial push/pull

Tags: version-control, mercurial, progress-bar, push, pull

Is it possible to get Mercurial to show progress of long-running push or pull operation? Google tells me basically "no", but does somebody know better? I was expecting something like `hg pull -v`...

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
hg pull -v
```

-v / --verbose

is a global option that applies to all sub-functions.

If you want extra data:

```
 hg --debug -v pull
```

Answer (score 86):

*Mercurial 3.5 has progress enabled by default.*

Earlier versions can use the standard [progress extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ProgressExtension) shipped since version 1.5. Simply enable the extension by adding this to your [hgrc](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html) file:

```
[extensions]
progress =
```

You will then see progress bars on clone, push, pull, and other operations. The progress bars are only shown after an initial delay of 3 seconds by default. You can easily change this by adding:

```
[progress]
delay = 1.5
```

to your hgrc file. See `hg help progress` after enabling the extension.

Comment: 6 years on - still an extension, it seems?

Comment: @jez: Actually no, Mercurial 3.5 moved the functionality into core and has it enabled by default. A little late for my taste, but at least it's there now :-)

Comment: Googling for this doesn't bring up any info on the built-in feature.  Wonder who I should blame for this…

Comment: @JürgenA.Erhard, when searching for "Mercurial progress bar" I found https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ProgressExtension. That page says (tersely) that the functionality is now in core. The relevant settings are then documented here: https://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#progress