# Firefox codebase checkout hangs

Tags: firefox, codebase

I'm planning to study Firefox codebase. I tried to checkout repository as follows:

```
C:\mozilla\firefox> hg clone http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central
destination directory: mozilla-central
requesting all changes
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
```

But it's now been 4-5 hrs. Nothing has been checked out yet. In #introduction IRC channel nobody is responding. Can I get some help from here?

Comment: Are you aware that you are checking out roughly 1 GB of data?

Comment: oops! I didn't know that. But in anyways, in 4-5 hrs it should have downloaded some files. But I can't see those in my file system. Beside, Can we have some progress indicator in checkout process?

Comment: A Mercurial repository checkout only adds data to the `.hg` subdirectory. By default Mercurial will also update the working directory after cloning the repository but that only happens after everything is downloaded. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308491/show-progress-of-mercurial-push-pull

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can take a while to download mozilla-central.  For me it takes about 15-20 minutes, but if you do not have a reliable connection, or not a fast connection, it can be significantly slower.

By the way you should not expect to see anything in your repository other than the .hg subdirectory until the process is done.  So it may seem hung, but it probably isn't.

**There are work arounds for people in your situation:**

> If you have a poor network connection that is preventing 'hg clone' from completing, you may want to try downloading a bundle of the repository you're interested in (which, unlike 'hg clone', can be resumed when network problems interrupt the download).

[Instructions and bundles are available here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Developer_Guide/Source_Code/Mercurial)

In general once you download the bundle you will do this:

> hg init src
>   cd src
>   hg unbundle /path/to/your/repository.hg

---

**Regarding your IRC experience:**

On a side note this week is the Mozilla all-hands week where all mozilla employees, contractors, and some contributors get together.  So your experiene on IRC was probably due to that. There is not as much presense on IRC during the Mozilla all-hands week.

Comment: Brian, Thanks. Here it goes Thumbs Up for your complete answer. I kept hg clone for night, so by the time I saw your answer, I already had the codebase checked out on my machine. That confirms your answer. In case of IRC, I will retry for further help.

Comment: Glad you got it to work, happy hacking! :)  For IRC as mentioned a lot of the people are busy during this week so try again after this week.  Also please wait around after asking for a while, sometimes it can take a while until someone happens to check into the chat to see if there's anything new.  Also if you don't get an answer on #introduction you can always try #developers.  Hope to see you around the community.