# How to tell progress of hg pull?

Tags: mercurial

```
$ hg pull
Password:
pulling from ssh://foo@bar.com:22//home/usr/xxx/repo
searching for changes
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
```

It then keep showing the above for 10+ min.  Is there a way to tell the progress and whether it's still live or already dead?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show progress of Mercurial push/pull](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308491/show-progress-of-mercurial-push-pull)

Comment: Okay.  You do deserve the tick ✓!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the [Progress](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ProgressExtension) extension by adding the following to your [HGRC](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html):

```
[extensions]
progress =
```

and/or use the verbose option:

```
hg pull -v
```

There is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308491/show-progress-of-mercurial-push-pull) on StackOverflow that may also be useful to you.

Answer (score 1):

The [progress extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ProgressExtension) is your friend. You can also add the `-v/--verbose` and `--debug` switches to `hg pull` see more data.

Answer (score 1):

As for your followup question: if Mercurial is tracking a file (that is, if you `hg add` and later `hg commit` `subdir1/subsubdir1/foobar.c`) then it wont ignore it. So `.hgignore` can only help you clean up the entries listed with `?` (the unknown files) in `hg status` — it wont have any effect on tracked files.

Comment: How to avoid downloading those files?  Those are too big.

Comment: I.e. that directory and contained files and directories are in `.hgignore` and I also ran `hg forget subdir1/subsubdir1` but still when I try to run `hg pull` from a different computer, it tries to download `subdir1/subsubdir1/foobar.c`?!

Comment: As you should be aware, Mercurial will always download the entire project history. So even if you `hg remove` a file, the file is still stored (in compressed form) inside the `.hg/` directory. When you clone or pull, you get the file — though it might not show up in the working copy any longer.